# ¿Cómo puedo establecer el ancho de una de columna de un dataGrdiView a su máximo posible?

Tags: c#, datagridview

tengo un `dataGrid` con 2 columnas "**código**" y "**descripción**" y a la hora de establecer los tamaños, no sé decirle a la columna "**descripción**" que su ancho ocupe el resto del `datagrid`.
Nada de lo que he leído me ha funcionado.
¿Me podéis echar un cable por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas en lo cierto lo apropiado es usar la propiedad `AutoSizeColumnsMode` solo que colocando el valor `Fill`, como sigue.

```
gridBrowser.Columns["descripcion"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

Answer (score 0):

utiliza esta forma

```
DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[1];// donde 1 es la columna descripcion
column.Width = 250;
```

[fuente](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.width?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewColumn_Width)

tambien puedes hacerle AutoSizeColumnsMode

Comment: El AutoSizeColumnsMode ya lo había probado:
`gridBrowser.Columns["descripcion"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;`
Pero no me ha funcionado.

Comment: Ah! en la respuesta de @EduardoReyes completo con el fill